# How to merge more then 255 cells in XLS using java

Tags: java, excel, spring, xlsx, xls

I'm trying to merge more then 255 cells using java code but there is error. **Maximum column number is 255** so how can i merge more then 255 cell in XLS using java??

```
public class CellMerge {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2, 10, 6, 300));
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/blackpearl/Downloads/newfilesss.xls")) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            System.out.println("good");
        }
    }

}
```

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maximum column number is 255
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressBase.validateColumn(CellRangeAddressBase.java:72)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressBase.validate(CellRangeAddressBase.java:54)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.addMergedRegion(HSSFSheet.java:641)
    at com.converting.CellMerge.main(CellMerge.java:28)
```

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried to use XSSFWorkbook (Excel 2007) instead of HSSFWorkbook (Excel 97)?

Comment: yes... its working fine. but i don't want in XSSFWorkbook formate. because i need HSSFWorkbook Formate.

Comment: Well, Excel 97 doesn't support more than 255 columns. It's a limitation of the format.

Comment: Ok.. so there is any another way to do this??

Comment: I get a feeling you have an XY problem here. Why would you want to do something like use more than 255 columns specifically in a file format that doesn't support 255 columns?

Comment: I'm working on Export functionality. we will show there campaign(that may be run for 1 year)data into excel sheet. and  we have some clients they have Excel 2003. thats why we need to merge over 255 cell in HSSFWorkbook.   Thank You

Comment: Well, Excel 2003 also doesn't support more than 255 columns. I would suggest you rotate the data, so that rows are columns and columns are rows. Unless, of course, you had more than 255 rows in your original plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because there is limitations of XLS file for merging the 255 cells.
But if you want your output in XLS then you can use multile sheet in a one workbook. and divide your data in 250-250 cells. then you can easily show your data to clients in XLS.
Thank You